# Can I reference property comments in constructor comments?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

If my class has a commented public property, which is assigned via constructor, can I reference its description from a description of constructor argument with the same name?

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// x description
    /// </summary>
    public int x { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// y description
    /// </summary>
    public int y { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor description
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">How do I reference x description from here?</param>
    /// <param name="y">And y description?</param>
    public MyClass(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't *include* the description, but you can link to the property documentation with the `<see>` tag. For example:

```
<param name="x">The initial value for <see cref="x"/></param>
```

As an aside, I would strongly urge you to follow .NET naming conventions, where public members start with capital letters.

Comment: But I still wonder how to use this cref, I opened the generated xml, only see x was replaced with x's full name. and did not see 'x description' in the intellisence either.

Comment: @LeiYang: No, as I said, that won't *include* the description - but when you generate the documentation, there'll be a link to the property within the HTML.

Comment: I believe this answer is outdated (not sure as of when). I provided a method as a separate answer that works as of C# 9 and maybe earlier.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using `<inheritdoc/>`, specifically by making use of the optional `cref` and `path` attributes.

Note: I'm unsure what language or framework version this became available, it works for me using .NET 5 / C# 9. If someone comments with a starting version I can edit.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc

For your example (the difference is within the `param` elements on the constructor XML comments):

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// x description
    /// </summary>
    public int x { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// y description
    /// </summary>
    public int y { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor description
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"><inheritdoc cref="x" path='/summary'/></param>
    /// <param name="y"><inheritdoc cref="y" path='/summary'/></param>
    public MyClass(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

This will make the constructor parameters inherit the summary comments from your parameters, reducing redundancy.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The entire `<inheritdoc>` tag shows up in the generated documentation instead of just the parsed contents of the summary field

Comment: @CassieDee it's hard for me to know exactly what your issue is without seeing the code. It might be worth asking a new question and include a minimal reproducible example, and if you comment with a link to that I'd be happy to take a look if no one beats me to it. Might be wise to reference this answer in the question itself and that you already tried what I have here to avoid it getting marked as duplicate. Please also include your .NET SDK version.

Comment: Works like a charm, so glad I learnt this!